# SSRS 2008 Fixing the Row Header

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In **SQL Server Reporting Services 2008**, I cannot always fix the Header row of a Tablix. Right-clicking the tablix and checking `Repeat header rows on each page` accomplishes nothing. Expanding the group panes to Advanced View and right-clicking numerous `(Static)` row group sections and changing properties `RepeatOnNewPage` to `True` works only if done in conjunction with setting `KeepWithGroup` to `After`.

But that often disallows compilation since it is considered an `rsInvalidKeepWithGroupOnDynamicTablixMember` error: Visial Studio 2008 tells me *...A TablixMember that is dynamic (i.e., has a Group specified) or has dynamic descendants must have the KeepWithGroup property set to "None".* It seems random as to whether I can set this property on this `(Static)` tablix member.

*Is there an easy, intuitive way to fix a header row on an **SSRS 08** Tablix?*

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488900

Comment: Also, this Microsoft connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=337720

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reporting Services: Tablix RepeatColumnHeaders doesn't work on some reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488900/reporting-services-tablix-repeatcolumnheaders-doesnt-work-on-some-reports)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

YES! You actually need to use the advanced group functions in the bottom half of the report design screen, and change the properties for the group. You can only freeze the header rows on the outermost static group of the report.

With your report in design view, make sure the group window with row groups and column groups are showing at the bottom of your screen.  At the far right of the top of the "Column Groups" pane, there is a small down arrow (**not the down arrow on the group bar**).  Clicking that arrow will allow you to view advanced properties. When you select advanced properties you will see your groups in orange bars and the static groups in gray, you must (must, must) choose the top static group.  You do want to make sure that the text headers you want to freeze are in this top most row.

In the properties window change the FixedData property to True.

Also, the check box for "Show header rows on each page" in the tabliix properties window does not work either, you also need to set that in the properties box. Set "RepeaOnNewPage" property to True.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks! Somehow I've just never seen that little down arrow, or just dismissed it as not very useful.