# Freezing A Row In SSRS Report Body

Tags: reporting-services

Thanks in advance. I need to know how to freeze a row in the body part of a ssrs report. I'm using the tool: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 ; version 9.0

Comment: What do you mean by 'freeze a row' ?

Comment: it should be shown always even while scrolling the page...

Comment: as far as I know you can only do this with table headers or report headers

Comment: could you please explain briefly the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with any static row.

On the far right of the Row Groups and Column Groups Sections there is a little down arrow. Click that and select 'Advanced Mode'

Now in the row groups section you can select any static row. Choose one corresponding to the row you want to freeze (the cells will highlight when you click) and set the property FixedData = True

Comment: For more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368861/ssrs-2008-fixing-the-row-header