# Keep SSRS report row groups visible while horizontal scroling

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have made SSRS drilldown report. I added row groups, so I can toggle visibility of the row group. But my report also have large number of columns, so I want to freeze first 3 columns of the report for horizontal scrolling. I know I can do this with fixed data property of the column group, but this first 3 columns in the table are row group columns, so I don't know is it possible to make them fixed while horizontal scrolling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 Fixing the Row Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368861/ssrs-2008-fixing-the-row-header)

Comment: I don't want to fix row header, I want to fix first 3 columns, with their header and data, for right-left scrolling, but that columns does not belongs to column groups, but in row groups, so I can not set fixed data to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found an answer: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15c68b00-ba78-499e-b0b8-6e684e875210/ssrs-2008-r2-fixed-row-on-matrix-while-scrolling-horizontally):

"1. Right-click the gray handle above the row group name, then select “Tablix Properties”.
2. Check “Header should remain visible while scrolling” in the Row Headers pane.

After complete the steps above, we find that the row group remains on left side of screen when we scroll horizontally.

Note:  If Month-Year row group is put before the SalesDate row group, the Month-Year group will freeze with SalesDate together. "